# Open Telegram link from LinkedIn mobile application browser

Tags: html, iphone, linkedin-api, telegram, html-target

On iPhone, I'm unable to open Telegram HTTPS JOIN CHANNEL link from LinkedIn mobile application browser. It always opens webpage in embedded browser and JOIN CHANNEL button is not reacting on clicks and nothing happens.

Is there any way to form Telegram link on my webpage in order be able to open it from LinkedIn mobile application embedded browser?

Comment: If you open that web page in the mobile safari browser and click on the button, is it opening telegram app?

Comment: Yes, it is working properly this way

Comment: ok, I have faced the same issue with the SalesForce app. They might be using custom web views with limited user actions. I have tried to open my own app from SalesForce's web view from a web page. But I couldn't